# Armchart doesn't show the line on zoom

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using amcharts with react.

When I use standart date value chart on my data I don't see the line when I zoom.

here is working exampele:

```
//Example of data where it works
[{
  "date": new Date(2018, 0, 1),
  "value": 450,
  "value2": 362,
  "value3": 699
}
```

https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/OdZygY

**and then example with my custom data:**

```
//Example of custom data where it doesn't work  
[{"highDate":"2020-01-22T21:00:00.000Z","highValue":"74.1300"}...
```

https://codepen.io/svv2014/pen/WNbPpRd

On the first example zoom works normally and it doesn't on the second with my data.

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. My data was sorted from newest to latest.

And **amchart** looks very sensitive to this when you zoom.

so solution was to revers the order

```
let data = [
  {
    "highDate": "2020-01-22T21:00:00.000Z",
    "highValue": 74.1300,
  },
  {
    "highDate": "2020-01-22T20:59:00.000Z",
    "highValue": 74.0770
  },
  {
    "highDate": "2020-01-22T20:58:00.000Z",
    "highValue": 74.1100
  },
  {
    "highDate": "2020-01-22T20:57:00.000Z",
    "highValue": 74.0966
  },...

// solution
data = data.reverse();
```

https://codepen.io/svv2014/pen/WNbPpRd

it the codepen snippets you can uncomment solution to see how it works.